# Rails 3 - How to set attributes on :has_many : trough association with radio button

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, many-to-many

It's been two days now that I read blogs, watch railcasts, read books, etc. and I can`t find an elegant solution to my problem.

Context: I have a multiple businesses that can have multiple contact_persons. Also, each business must have one primary contact_person at all time.  So I have a many to many relationship between business and contact_person trough a business_contact_persons table.

```
class Business < AR
has_many :business_contact_persons, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :contact_persons, :through => :business_contact_persons


class ContactPersons < AR
has_many :business_contact_persons, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :business, :through => :business_contact_persons


class BusinessContactPerson < AR
belongs_to :business
belongs_to :contact_person

#Primary is a boolean in the database
attr_accessible :primary, :contact_id, :business_id
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve in my business view is to permit the users to select every contact_person they would like to assign a particular business, AND, to select the one they would like to be the primary contact. So in my new business view I'm able to display a group of check box displaying all the available contact_persons, and a radio_button group with the same list of contact_persons to select the primary.

To save the business, I use this in my controller:

```
@business.attributes = params[:business]
```

and it works for saving the business_contact_persons because it access the attributes trough

```
params[:business][:contact_person_ids]
```

But that do not assign my primary business_contact_persons boolean fields for the one selected by the user. And to make things worst, how I will take care of the edit business, since a user could change the primary contact_person for a business.

Also, an idea about how I could validate that a business have a primary contact_person assigned would be very nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use Rails form tag helpers.

#### Create your own select tag:

You can create your own select tag, with its own name, for example "bcp" meaning business contact person. You create your own options and there are shortcuts for creating options from collections.

#### Controller:

In your controller, you get the param:

```
bcp = BusinessContactPerson.find(params[:bcp])
bcp.primary = true
bcp.save!
```

Rails has a bunch of helpers for building your own forms:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

#### before_validation:

You would create/update the BCP before you validate the Business model.

You may want to look at the ActiveRecord #before_validation callback.

Also see #inverse_of setting to ensure the #belongs_to finds the same record.

(I'm not certain this will all work-- these are the starting points that I would try)

Comment: Thanks Joel. But if I understand your answer correctly, all BusinessContactPerson will be created by the Business with the ContactPersonIds attributes of the checkbox group.  Then I will find which one is the primary by getting the radio button, which will be a totally different attributes.  So the businessContactPerson will be created _before_ it is assigned as the primary.  So how the validation verifying that "always a primary contact assigned" will work on my Business model?

Comment: @Alain You would create/update the BCP before you validate the Business model. You may want to look at the ActiveRecord #before_validation callback and #inverse_of setting to ensure the #belongs_to finds the same record. I'm not certain this will all work-- these are the starting points that I would try. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks again Joel. I think your last comment really answers my problem.